# NULL vs Empty String usage

Tags: string, null, is-empty, isnullorempty

I have been wondering recently about usage of empty string vs null.

I know what these values mean, but I wonder when I should use each? It is not about exact programming language or approach.

Comment: every programming language is different and has a different (similar sometimes) behaviour

Comment: but shortly: string initialized with null means that there's no string at all, empty string means there's a string but it's empty, if someone else is using your API then you might decide to not accept null or empty so you have to check for both.

Answer (score 2):

As a general guideline, I avoid using `null` no matter what.

`null` is not an object, it can't do anything and you can't expect anything from it. It will evenatually leak as a rather obscure `NullPointerException`. You can't access any field or any method in `null` and trying to do so, will lead you to the aforementioned excpetion.

You can avoid using it with:

- [`Null Object`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern) pattern
- Raising `Exception` with a more useful than message than an empty `NullPointerException`
- Designing your classes to have its fields `private final` therefore avoiding nulls by design

Answer (score 1):

Moste of the time you want to prevent both. 
The difference is that a null value is returned most of the time when you try to use a variable which doesn't exist or has not been instantiated by you or the programm. 
The empty string is most of the time a human approach of emptying a variable which already exists.